# How to install the latest bfgminer binaries directly from terminal without 'aptitude' on a raspberry pi 4 8gb running raspbian?

Tags: mining-theory, miner-configuration

months ago I found an entry on StackExchange or somewhere else on how to install the latest (!) bfgminer binaries directly from terminal. I can not find the stackexchange post, no matter how deep I search here / on Google.

I do not remember if it was a download directly from luke-jr's website via terminal or from somewhere else. I only remember that it was done via the terminal and it created an executeable shortcut in the /bin/ and/or /usr/bin/ folder.

Visiting the website from luke-jr triggers my anti virus software telling me the website is infected or hosts infected files. So I can't visit it directly sadly.

Months ago I tried it out on my old RPi and it worked just fine. But now that I had to switch to a newer RPi I can not find or remember the correct terminal command for installing bfgminer binaries directly.

More details about why I need the binaries:
Compiling prints out LOTS of errors for me.
Using 'sudo aptitude install bfgminer' needs "aptitude" installed, so I tried to install it and it returned lots of errors, most of the package files where not downloadable (my Internet connection is fine by the way).

Can you help me out with a terminal command that let's me successfully install bfgminer on raspbian?
On my old Pi I managed to install it without aptitude and without compiling it first.

Thanks so far!

Answer (score 1):

Update: sudo apt-get install bfgminer failed several times, as the same for sudo apt-get install cgminer.
After trying numerous times it finally worked!
No more need to download it from this website, got it.
Thread can be closed. Thank you anyway for your time! :)